# REST API pagination from multiple sources

Tags: api, rest, pagination, odata

I am trying to write a pass through REST API which enumerates data from multiple data sources.
I need to provide seamless pagination across these data sources.
What are my options?

One option I thought is to have continumationToken passed to client which has details about data sources which are already enumerated, so the current call can start from the point where previous call stopped. However, this can make the token large if we have more number of data sources.

Comment: What's large, and what's too large? Could you store the pagination info in some (temporary) storage and just give the client some token?

Comment: Large can be 50 sources! As the API is REST there is no state information stored in the service!